# CSS: keeping div size the same when enlarging the font size

Tags: html, css

I want to enlarge the font-size of the links when using hovers the mouse on the link, which is easily achieved by the following line in the CSS code.

```
a:hover {font-size:110%}
```

However, when the link font-size increases, it would also "inflate" the size of the `<div>` that my links are in, which would "squeeze" the div underneath it and make the whole page "shake".

Is there a way to keep the size of the `<div>` the same, while the link font-size enlarges?

Comment: it'd be better if you shared your HTML/CSS which you already have.
Also, try adding "overflow: hidden" to the said div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make your `div` have a fixed size, and with a `position:absolute;` for your `<a>`, making its font larger will not affect the `<div>`.

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/AliBassam/EsNSe/)**

**HTML**

```
<div id="content">
    <a href="#">Hey there</a>
</div>
<div id="more">More Divs</div>
```

**CSS**

```
a
{
    font-size:16px;
    position:absolute;

}
a:hover
{
    font-size:110%;
}
#content
{
    position:relative;
    height:20px;
}
```

Comment: All the solutions work but I felt like this is the easiest and most intuitive one

Answer (score 1):

The above code works, but here is another solution that might apply to you as well.
there is no reason to use % , and if there is, this doce still works.

there are 2 Examples: font size as a pixel and font size as a percent.

http://jsfiddle.net/MJUjP/

HTML

```
<div class="main">
    <div class="content">
        PX
    </div>
</div>

<div class="main">
    <div class="content2">
        %
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.main {
    /*Styling for better viweing*/
    background: #000fff;
    float:left;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
}
.content{
     /*Styling for better viweing*/
    background: #ff0000;
    margin: 8px;
    border: #000 1px solid;
    float:left;
    text-align: center;

    /*Set Size of DIV snd font*/
    height:80px;
    width:80px;
    font-size:30px;

    /*Optional to hide overflow*/
    overflow-x:hidden;
    overflow-y:hidden;
}
.content:hover{
    /*Set New Font Size*/
    font-size:80px;
}


.content2{
     /*Styling for better viweing*/
    background: #ff0000;
    margin: 8px;
    border: #000 1px solid;
    float:left;
    text-align: center;

    /*Set Size of DIV snd font*/
    height:80px;
    width:80px;
    font-size:100%;
    line-height:100%;

    /*Optional to hide overflow*/
    overflow-x:hidden;
    overflow-y:hidden;
}
.content2:hover{
    /*Set New Font Size*/
    font-size:800%;
    line-height:110%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<div id="mydiv">
   <a href="#">Link</a>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#mydiv a {
   display:block;
   font: 16px/30px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
   border:1px solid #CCC;
   padding:10px;
}
#mydiv a:hover {
   font-size: 200%;
}
```

View live http://jsfiddle.net/imtiazmasrur/rqMLd/

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are using the `em` length value on the height of your `div`. That's normally not a bad thing, but if you increase the font-size you also increase the value of `em`. Normally `1 em = 16px`.

You could us the `rem` length value on the `height` attribute of your `div`. That way you use the standard font-size of the html root. ( As long as you didn't do something like this `html { font-size 35px; }`. That would change the standard value of `em` to `35px`. )

Or you could go oldschool and use the `px` length value on your `div`.